# Exoplayer issue while playing video on Video player

Tags: flutter

Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(VideoError, Video player had error com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlaybackException: MediaCodecVideoRenderer error, index=0, format=Format(1, null, null, video/avc, avc1.64001E, -1, null, [480, 480, 29.999588], [-1, -1]), format_supported=YES, null, null)

Comment: have you got the solution?

Comment: Not yet @suyashsaurabh. Right now I haven't look for that issue cause I don't have much time for that to Research and other things So, I thought for now let's move on until unless someone will provide me a better solution for Exoplayer Issue.